# Android App- speech to text in Indian English

Tags: android, speech-to-text, recognizer-intent

I am developing an Android App that uses speech to text recognition.I have used RecognizerIntent and i know about the link
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#EXTRA_LANGUAGE
But this allows US-english. I want the speech recognizer to recognize Indian Englishas i need the App to recognize Indian names. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the linked document says, the value is a "IETF language tag (as defined by BCP 47)". Which values are actually supported depends on the speech recognizer that you are using. E.g. Google's recognizer supports `en-IN`, so if you are using Google's recognizer then you could try to set the value of `EXTRA_LANGUAGE` to `en-IN` and test if Indian names will be recognized.